# Wordpress Theme "An error occurred - second level - -32300:transport error - HTTP status code was not 200"

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a website and whenever I am trying to add a post on the wp-admin panel using **"Types Plugin"** I receive this error when clicked on the "Publish" button which states **"An error occurred - second level - -32300:transport error - HTTP status code was not 200"** and the URL address is "/wp-admin/post.php". And if here I refresh the page I am routed to the Posts page instead of that "Types" and then if go that "Types Custom Post" there I can see that the post was added. If I try to update this post then there is no error message and everything is normal. This is happening only when I am trying to add a custom post through "Types".

I tried to turn off all the other plugins but still the error is there, then I tried to switch the theme to "Twenty Thirteen". Now if I add the custom post everything is fine I don't find any error.

Comment: Do you have any further information on the "Types" plugin you mention?

Comment: Basically this plugin is used to make custom post types instead of using the Wordpress based specific post. Like we can add custom fields, etc in this plugin to make our backend more easier than earlier. If I want to have a collection of Books I can create a Category "Books" in the Types plugin and then I can easily add the fields which I want to have in this category posts. This is how it works with the "Types".

Comment: Ok - the error implies some issue with the GET/POST to a destination URL, so whilst the post seems to succeed I would check (by using the network aspect of the developer tools in your browser) to see if either more than 1 request is being sent (and one of those is failing) or there is a redirect happening that is returning an HTTP status other than 200.